# If/else clause on loop statement with re.search does not work (python)

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I want to parse lines of a file and get IP adresses.
I use re.search  and I want to print both :
- the IP's
- the string 'None' when there's not an IP

Considering the file corresponds to the variable logfile, I wrote this snippet :

```
import re, sys

regexip = r'(?!91.134.143.128)[0-9]{2,3}[.][0-9]{2,3}[.][0-9]{2,3}[.][0-9]{2,3}'
logfile = '91.12.13.14, 65.12.45.78, aaa'

my_iplist = re.findall(regexip,logfile)
for ii in my_iplist:
    if re.search (regexip,logfile):
        print ii
    else:
        print 'None'
```

The problem is that I only get these results...

> 91.12.13.14
>   65.12.45.78

... whereas I want to have :

> 91.12.13.14
>   65.12.45.78
>   None

That else statement does not work. I suppose there's something I do wrong but I don't know what it is..
Any help would be very appreciated.
Thanks !

Comment: @cdarke : log is logfile, I just modified this

Comment: It's because `re.findall` only returns the matches, take a look at what you have in `my_iplist`

Comment: Does your log only contains a single line or are `,`s are actually `\n`s here? A line can contain several IPs, can't it?

Comment: As a side note, using the `{2,3}` quantifier is most likely a mistake, I don't see why it wouldn't be `{1,3}` if you're trying to catch generic IPv4 addresses.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55648564/3832970) for a safer approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, use `r'(?<![0-9])(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(?:\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)){3}(?![0-9])'` to actually match [valid IPs](https://www.regular-expressions.info/ip.html). You may filter out the "unwelcome" IP once you have a match.

Now, if you have a single IP per line, use `re.search` like this

```
import sys, re

regexip = r'(?<![0-9])(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(?:\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)){3}(?![0-9])'
result = []
with open(your_log_file_path, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        m = re.search(regexip, line)
        if not m:
            result.append(None)
        else:
            if m.group() != "91.134.143.128":
                result.append(m.group())
            else:
                result.append(None)
```

If you have several unwelcome IPs, define them in a list:

```
uwelcome_ips = ["91.134.143.128", "91.134.143.129"]
```

and then

```
if m.group() not in uwelcome_ips:
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay.. great it works !! Thank you very much for your help !

Answer (score 1):

`else` will never be executed because `my_iplist` only contains valid IP's. `re.findall` will return all the matches. All the strings that does not match will not be returned.

To achieve your desired output, you need to split the string by `", "`, then test each against the regex:

```
lines = logfile.split("\n")
nested_ips = map(lambda x: x.split(", "), lines)
ips = reduce(list.__add__, nested_ips)
for ii in ips:
    if re.search (regexip,ii):
        print ii
    else:
        print 'None'
```

You should also change your regex to have start and end anchors:

```
regexip = r'^(?!91.134.143.128)[0-9]{2,3}[.][0-9]{2,3}[.][0-9]{2,3}[.][0-9]{2,3}$'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It helps me a lot. But when it's a log file, I should use split("\n). But the result return the whole line and not the IP only.

Comment: You need to split the whole file by `"\n"`, and split _each line_ by `", "`. @Julien

Comment: Do I split each line on the "ii" result ?

Answer (score 0):

`re.findall` does not keep the unmatched things so you'll have to check line by line:

```
for i in logfile.split(','):
    match = re.search(regexip, i)
    if match: 
        print match.group(0)
    else: 
        print "None"
```

Since your logfile is a file you can instead loop on the lines:

```
for line in open("logfile.log", "r"):
    match = re.search(regexip, line.strip())
    if match:
        print match.group(0)
     else:
        print "None"
```

Here's what my `logfile.log` file looks like:

```
91.12.13.14ezrtqsyu
65.12.45.78 aert
aaa
```

And the output:

```
91.12.13.14
65.12.45.78
None
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It helps me a lot. But when it's a log file, I should use split("\n). But the result return the whole line and not the IP only.

Comment: I think you should loop over the file instead of using `split('\n')`